# how to get Date from Json and put it on object Spring boot

Tags: java, json, spring, date, spring-boot

I'm getting a Json object and I have a date format that I need to pass to object and persist in the database 
 im using this method

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/pacientes")
    public HttpStatus cadastrarPacientes(@RequestBody ObjectNode json) {


            Entidades entidades = new Entidades();
            entidades.setIdEntidade(json.get("pessoa").get("entidade").get("idEntidade").asLong());

            Pessoas pessoas = new Pessoas();
            pessoas.setNome(json.get("pessoa").get("nome").textValue());
            pessoas.setNomeSocial(json.get("pessoa").get("nomeSocial").textValue());
            pessoas.setFoto(json.get("pessoa").get("foto").textValue());
            pessoas.setNomeSocial(json.get("pessoa").get("nomePai").textValue());
            pessoas.setNomeMae(json.get("pessoa").get("nomeMae").textValue());
            --here is date //pessoas.setDataNascimento((json.get("pessoa").get("dataNascimento").textValue()); 
}
```

how i can convert ?

Comment: get it as a string and parse it as u want

Comment: but i have i type date in my model class

Comment: Why don't you map your JSON to a proper class, with named and typed properties? That would make the code simpler and safer. Other than that, google for "how to parse a date in Java". This is basic stuff.

Comment: @JBNizet how i do that ?

Comment: You write a class that has the same structure as your JSON, and let Jackson do the job for you. Jackson is documented. Read the documentation.

Comment: @JB Nizet is correct you can use jackson databind